# Filter Keras image_dataset_from_directory classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, kaggle

I'm importing dataset from kaggle, it has 15 classess and I need only 10 classes from them, how can I filtered these classes into my dataset?

I am trying this code

```
image_size= 256
batch_size=8
channels=3
epochs=50

dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('/kaggle/input/plant-village/PlantVillage',
                                                              seed=123,
                                                              shuffle=True,
                                                              image_size=(image_size,image_size),
                                                              batch_size=batch_size)
dataset.class_names
```

### the results are

Found 20638 files belonging to 15 classes.
['Pepper__bell___Bacterial_spot',
'Pepper__bell___healthy',
'Potato___Early_blight',
'Potato___Late_blight',
'Potato___healthy',
'Tomato_Bacterial_spot',
'Tomato_Early_blight',
'Tomato_Late_blight',
'Tomato_Leaf_Mold',
'Tomato_Septoria_leaf_spot',
'Tomato_Spider_mites_Two_spotted_spider_mite',
'Tomato__Target_Spot',
'Tomato__Tomato_YellowLeaf__Curl_Virus',
'Tomato__Tomato_mosaic_virus',
'Tomato_healthy']

### I expect only these claases

```
desired_classes = [
    'Tomato_Bacterial_spot',
    'Tomato_Early_blight',
    'Tomato_Late_blight',
    'Tomato_Leaf_Mold',
    'Tomato_Septoria_leaf_spot',
    'Tomato_Spider_mites_Two_spotted_spider_mite',
    'Tomato__Target_Spot',
    'Tomato__Tomato_YellowLeaf__Curl_Virus',
    'Tomato__Tomato_mosaic_virus',
    'Tomato_healthy'
]
```

Comment: @Nicholas it really works, you saved me a lot of time even though I searched it for GPT, but I could not find the right solution. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` because you can directly filter classes.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import (
    DirectoryIterator, ImageDataGenerator
)

directory = r'path/to/image/directory'
batch_size = 10
image_size = 256

img_iterator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255.
)

iterator = DirectoryIterator(
    directory=directory,
    image_data_generator=img_iterator,
    classes=desired_classes,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```